# How do you set the language version for C# projects when generating projects with CMake?

Tags: c#, cmake

[Version 3.8 of CMake supports generating Visual Studio C# projects](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html#c).  By default, it sets the language version ("LangVersion") to version 3 in the .csproj file.  I need to change to a more recent language version, like version 6.

How do I override the language version in my `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set this as a compile flag on a target:

```
project(MyProject CSharp)
add_executable(MyExe main.cs)
target_compile_options(MyExe PRIVATE "/langversion:6")
```

Alternatively, you can set the global variable, to apply it to all future targets:

```
set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:6")
```

Comment: I chose the set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:6") method.  Thanks!

Comment: Your options for `langversion` are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/langversion-compiler-option). For example, you can specify `"/langversion:latest"` to tell the compiler to accept syntax for the latest version of C# it can support.

Comment: This solution does not work with cmake 3.14 and VS2019.  CMake writes to value "lanversion" to the element <AdditionalOptions> </AdditionalOptions> in csproj file. But VS expects it will be in <LangVersion></LangVersion>.